# external jar file breaks gwt/glassfish compile

Tags: java, gwt, glassfish

I'm trying to add a specific external jar file to my Eclipse GWT project (I can get other external jar files to work).

I can get the GWT "Web Application Starter Project" to run on a Glassfish server (thanks to [this](http://rmapper.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/gwt-development-mode-with-hot-deployed-glassfish-in-eclipse-2/) beginner friendly tutorial). However, when I add the jar file (compiled from a wsdl web service project) and try to run the project as Web Application I just get the following message

*Waiting for launch URLs...*

and nothing else. I'm also not able to compile the project with this jar included. Any debugging advice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Glassfish independently from Eclipse, and deploy your application/ear on it as per usual. Then you can check the logs of glassfish and see whats wrong.

In case Eclipse cant make the .ear or .war, thats then another problem (for now) and not with glassfish deployment. Are you using maven or ant for your build? Perhaps the build script is doing something that makes it wait... perhaps its attempting to download a jar from somewhere but doesnt get a response so it waits?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, I've not started using Maven (it's on my  todo-list, promise). Turns out the problem was with the build class path order. I had to place the jar file above the GWT SDK for it to compile.